# Persisting of DataFrames in transformation workflows

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to run a series of transformation over 3 DataFrames. After each transformation, I want to persist DF and save it to text file. The steps I am doing is as follows.

**Step0:**
Create DF1
Create DF2
Create DF3
Create DF4
(no persist no save yet)

**Step1:**
Create RESULT-DF1 by joining DF1 and DF2
Persist it to disk and memory
Save it to text file

**Step2:**
Create RESULT-DF2 by joining RESULT-DF1 and DF3
Persist it to disk and memory
Save it to text file

**Step3:**
Create RESULT-DF3 by joining RESULT-DF2 and DF4
Persist it to disk and memory
Save it to text file

**Observation:**
Number of tasks created at Step1 is 601
Number of tasks created at Step2 is 1004 (Didn't skip anything)
Number of tasks created at Step3 is 1400 (Skipped 400 tasks)

As different approach, I broke above steps into three different runs. ie;

- Start, Load DF1 and DF2, Do Step1, Save RESULT-DF1 & exit
- Start, Load DF3, Load RESULT-DF1 from file, do Step2, save RESULT-DF2
  & exit
- Start, Load DF4, Load RESULT-DF2 from file, do Step3, save RESULT-DF3
  & exit

Later approach runs faster.

**My question is:**
Am missing something on the persisting side in first approach?
Why Step2 run didn't just use result from Step1 without redoing all it's tasks even after persisting (with only 601 tasks instead of 1004)?
What are some good reads about best practices, when implementing such series of transformation workflows?

Comment: How are you persisting the DataFrames and how are joining them. Please share the code.

Comment: I have tried this scenario and got the reason for this behaviour. Can you please give me the following details: 1) Cluster memory and 2) size of files used to create DF1,DF2,DF3

Comment: It is a 4 + 1 cluster. All five nodes has 32 GB. Ran four executors. Provided 20 GB as executor memory and 20 GB as driver memory. Data size is about 50 to 75 GB per source.

Comment: @pankajarora joining using dataframes sql (inner join). For persist, tried: resDf1.persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY()) and resDf1.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK())

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no code provided, I will assume that the join operations you are performing are different each time (on different attributes and data). Even if you have cached the data frames Spark needs to resolve each join into multiple stages and tasks. The Catalyst optimizer is responsible to create the Logical (initial and optimized) and Physical plan for your query. Given this sequence of execution each time a new plan must be computed based on your query and the respective dataset (the data frame could become smaller or bigger after each join).

Given that the tasks are increasing from data frame to data frame after each join, it is possible that your datasets are getting bigger and/or you perform the join operation on multiple attributes. However I cannot understand what you mean by exit in your second approach.

For further reading I would suggest the following: 
https://databricks.com/blog/2015/04/13/deep-dive-into-spark-sqls-catalyst-optimizer.html

Comment: By "exit" in second approach, I meant running three programs. First program does something, saves results and stops. Second program loads first program's results, does something, saves results and stops...

Comment: Can you please help? @maasg

Answer (score 0):

In you case, please consider that how Spark SQL query optimizer works. One of the cases where Catalyst optimizer currently runs into challenges is with very large query plans. These query plans tend to be the result of iterative algorithms, like graph algorithms or machine learning algorithms. One simple work around for this is converting the data to an RDD and back to DataFrame/Dataset at the end of each iteration.

I encountered the exactly same issue as what you described above. And this workaround really helped.

~Erik